# running multiple tests via npm test and jspm

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs, jspm, node.js-tape

I'm using [jspm](https://github.com/jspm/jspm-cli) to manage the modules in my project.

I'd like to write tests using [tape](https://github.com/substack/tape) and using ES6 syntax.

I'd like to be able to run those tests from the command line using `npm test`.

If I run `jspm run test/example.js` directly from the command line, the test runs.

If I add

```
"scripts" : {
    "test" : "jspm run test/example.js"
}
```

to `package.json` and then run `npm test`, the test runs.

So far so good, but I'd like to be have multiple tests in the `test` dir. `jspm run` only seems to support one module at a time.

If I replace `jspm run` with `babel-node`, I get `Error: Cannot find module 'tape'`. This error makes sense to me i.e `babel-node` doesn't know where `tape` is, only `jspm` does.

So is there a way of saying to `npm test`, "run all these tests in here and if you can't find a module, ask jspm"?

Here is my sample test

```
import test from 'tape';

test('A passing test', (assert) => {

  assert.pass('This test will pass.');

  assert.end();
});

test('Assertions with tape.', (assert) => {
  const expected = 'something to test';
  const actual = 'sonething to test';

  assert.equal(actual, expected,
    'Given two mismatched values, .equal() should produce a nice bug report');

  assert.end();
});
```

Here is my directory structure.

```
  package.json
  test
    | - example.js
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "playground",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "jspm": {
    "devDependencies": {
      "babel": "npm:babel-core@^5.8.24",
      "babel-runtime": "npm:babel-runtime@^5.8.24",
      "core-js": "npm:core-js@^1.1.4",
      "tape": "npm:tape@^4.2.2"
    }
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jspm": "^0.16.13"
  },
  "scripts" : {
    "test" : "jspm run test/example.js" //<-- what should I put here?
  }

}
```

Comment: I can't test with JSPM right now, but I use this with NPM: `babel-node $(which tape) \"./test/**/*.js\" | faucet`

Answer (score 0):

1) You need some kind of a test runner. Consider using karma with karma-jspm plugin: https://github.com/Workiva/karma-jspm Since you want to use tape, consider adding karma-tap https://github.com/mapbox/karma-tap

It looks like you want to test your code in Node but since JSPM is a package manager for the browser it makes more sense to use karma and run tests in the browser/headless browser.

2) If you need to test some non-browser code, consider using babel-node with conventional test runners such as mocha. You don't need JSPM for this.

3) Take a look at this sample project https://github.com/curran/jspm-mocha-example I believe it managed to combine jspm, mocha and node execution

Comment: I may go down the karma route eventually. For now though I'm just going with an earlier answer that was deleted pretty quickly for some reason. That answer suggested doing `npm install -D tape` and putting `babel-node node_modules/.bin/tape test/**/*.js` in `package.json`.

Comment: I have created a project that helps to setup browser tests for JSPM projects https://github.com/OrKoN/jspm-testem